# How to configure vagrant venv in pycharm on MAC os?

Tags: python, vagrant, pycharm, virtualbox, python-venv

I created virtual box on my local system and then I did **vagrant up** in project root directory.

I find there is 2 python version. First is *python 2.7* available on **/usr/bin/python** location and second is *python 2.7.15* available on **source /opt/venv/bin/activate**.

I opened my project in Pycharm IDE.But getting `Unresolved reference` for some modules and getting `No module named` for some module.

Then I tried to gave path to python interpreter path but showing python 2.7 version path: **/usr/bin/python**.
[image]

But I want python 2.7.15 path which is available in under **source /opt/venv/bin/activate** folder

Please give tell me How can I configure *venv* which is under **source /opt/venv/bin/activate** path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a new Vagrant based interpreter with correct venv in the path:

[image]